# Skip over bad records in SSJS loop and continue processing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I have created this SSJS Loop, but it will stop when a record is considered "bad". How do I skip over this record to continue the process?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
var AddedToday= "1";
var OrdersDE = DataExtension.Init("DEName");
var rows = OrdersDE.Rows.Lookup(["AddedToday"], [AddedToday]);

if(rows.length >= 1) 
  {
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
      {
        StyleVAR = rows[i]["Style"];
        Style2VAR = rows[i]["Style2"];
        PreferredStoreVAR = rows[i]["PreferredStore"];
        EmailVAR = rows[i]["Email"]; 
    var url = 'https://[MID].collect.igodigital.com/c2/[MID]/track_page_view?payload={[payload]}}}';
    var response = HTTP.Get(url);
        var result = OrdersDE.Rows.Update({Profile:'test'}, ['Email'],[EmailVAR]);
    
      }
}
else {Write("No items to display");}

  }catch(e){
    var errorMsg = Stringify(e)
    Write("Oops, something went wrong!<br>Please contact info@email.com so we can help you finalize your request.");
    var targetDE = 'DENAME'; //pass external key of the target DE      
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init(targetDE);
    logDE.Rows.Add({ message: errorMsg, "place":"cloudpage"});
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give more info on how a record would be 'considered bad'? Is it that the row does not exist? The variables do not match expected values/types? Update/Lookup fails? ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a more granular approach with your try-catches as currently you have pretty much your whole code wrapped in one - an error on any level will stop it from executing.

You can do checks on two levels:

1. See if the lookup found your source DE
2. If the operation on each individual level was successful

Then the code could look like this:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var rows = []; //

try{
    var AddedToday= "1";
    var OrdersDE = DataExtension.Init("DEName");
    rows = OrdersDE.Rows.Lookup(["AddedToday"], [AddedToday]);
}catch(e){
    var errorMsg = Stringify(e)
    Write("Oops, something went wrong!<br>Please contact info@email.com so we can help you finalize your request.");
    var targetDE = 'DENAME'; //pass external key of the target DE      
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init(targetDE);
    logDE.Rows.Add({ message: errorMsg, "place":"cloudpage"});
}

if(rows.length >= 1) 
  {
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
        {
        StyleVAR = rows[i]["Style"];
        Style2VAR = rows[i]["Style2"];
        PreferredStoreVAR = rows[i]["PreferredStore"];
        EmailVAR = rows[i]["Email"]; 

        try {
            var url = 'https://[MID].collect.igodigital.com/c2/[MID]/track_page_view?payload={[payload]}}}';
            var response = HTTP.Get(url);
            var result = OrdersDE.Rows.Update({Profile:'test'}, ['Email'],[EmailVAR]);    
        } catch (rowError) {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
    else {Write("No items to display");
}

</script>
```

I've added `var rows = [];` at line 4, so that `rows.length` at row 18 does not throw and exception